# How can I delete my daughter's 3 Instagram accounts?

Tags: account-management, instagram

My daughter has three different accounts and I want to delete all of them. How can I do this?

Answer (score 1):

To delete someone else account, you must have their email address or username and password. First you need to login into that account to delete that.

If you have your daughter's all accounts login credentials, you can delete her accounts one by one.

From [Instagram Help Page](https://help.instagram.com/370452623149242):

> To permanently delete your account:
>
> 1. Go to [the **Delete Your Account** page](https://www.instagram.com/accounts/login/?next=/accounts/remove/request/permanent/). If you're not logged into Instagram on the web, you'll be asked to log in first. You can't delete your account from within the Instagram app.
> 2. Select an option from the drop-down menu next to **Why are you deleting your account?** and re-enter your password. The option to permanently delete your account will only appear after you've selected a reason from the menu.
> 3. Click or tap **Permanently delete my account**.

If you don't have login credentials for your daughter's accounts, you cannot delete them.

Answer (score -1):

- just follow these steps and delete them all:

> [image: 1]
>
> **https://instagram.com/accounts/remove/request/permanent/**
>
> **https://help.instagram.com/370452623149242**